# When TextView expanded below linerview is disappear

Tags: android

I have a problem when my `TextView` expanded with many texts the items below the `TextView` is disappeared.
I am talking about the `TextView`  with ID: `tvPostBody`
I added `ScrolleView` to make sure the text will display completely if the text is more than max lines of `TextView`

Here is my XML file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    tools:context="com.atjt.login.DisplayOnePost">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUserImage"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="127dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.13"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/no_image" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserFullName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="User Full Name"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPostTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                android:text="Post Title in Full"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPostBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNumberOfReplies"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvReply"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Reply" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="|" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNumberOfViews"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvViews"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Views" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="15-12-2017" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any suggestions,

Comment: Try to add ` android:minLines=""` to text view than check

Comment: Do you mean make the number for minimum lines?
I did that, but still not working.
 android:minLines="5"

Comment: Yes, and you can also specify max lines.

Comment: Still it not scrolling?

Comment: it is scrolling, but the problem is not in scrolling, the problem is on the items below that textview.
I can define max lines, but in this case, the text will not appear all.

Comment: Why you used `android:layout_height="495dp"` in Linear layout you can `use match_parent` or `wrap_content`

Comment: I used wrap_content and also it is the same

Answer (score 0):

Problem is

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

Here, height is specified as wrap_content and therefore, it may fill entire below area and view below it may not be visible.

You need to specify some height for this so that you views below it are always visible.

Comment: You are the guy 
This fixed the problem. But what if I need to make the height flexible? What I mean, now if I make the height 300dp for example, the small text will remain in a huge space.
any suggestion.

Comment: In that case, you can programatically set scrollview height.